# How to automatically import data from a blob csv file to sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to automatically import data from a blob csv file to sheet 
I wanna able to access new update from csv file 
But I have to download it from web any copy to google drive

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You might want to look here: [Import data from CSV file in Google Drive, to Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55990270/5415398)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import data from CSV file in Google Drive, to Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41282250/import-data-from-csv-file-in-google-drive-to-google-sheet)